# Can you make Dojo's query return single node if given #id?

Tags: javascript, dojo

Short question.

Dojo's `query module` always returns an array of nodes. Is there any way I can config/modify  it so that

```
var contentNode = query('#content')[0];
```

can be written

```
var contentNode = query('#content');
```

instead?

That extra `[0]` annoys me, especially when Id's are unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. I'm sure this is a very conscious API decision so the return value is always uniform.  That way the calling code doesn't need to know the details of the path and whether it would return a list or a single node.

`dojo.byId('content')` does what you want though. Perhaps you could use that instead?

Comment: Hmm okay. I know `byId`, but it's just a normalized `getElementById`. `query` returns a nodeList object with a lot of smart functions!